# Cauchy sequence under a uniform continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let , $f:(1,4)\to \mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous and $\{a_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(1,2)$.
>
> Consider:  $x_n=a_n^2f(a_n^2)$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{1+a_n^2}f(a_n^2)$
>
> Then which is correct ?
>
> (A) Both $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R$.
>
> (B) $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ but $\{y_n\}$ is not Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$.
>
> (C) $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ but $\{x_n\}$ is not Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$.
>
> (D) Neither $\{x_n\}$ nor $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$.

Since $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence so $\{a_n^2\}$ is also Cauchy sequence . As $f$ is uniformly continuous so, $f(a_n^2)$ is also Cauchy sequence.

So, both are convergent and so their product is also convergent and hence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence.

But what about $\{y_n\}$ ?

Comment: The argument you used for $\{ x_n \}$ is valid for $\{ y_n \}$ as well, since $t \mapsto \frac{1}{1+t^2}$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: $g(x):={1\over {1+x^2}}$ is a continuous function which takes a convergent sequence to a convergent sequence . Then $y_n=g(a_n)f(a_n^2)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** for $\{y_n\}$,

$$|y_n-y_m|=\left| \dfrac{f(a_n^2)}{(1+a_n^2)}-\dfrac{f(a_m^2)}{(1+a_m^2)}\right| \le \left| \dfrac{f(a_n^2)-f(a_m^2)}{(1+a_n^2)}\right|+|f(a_m^2)|\left| \dfrac{1}{1+a_n^2}-\dfrac{1}{1+a_m^2}\right| \le \dfrac{1}{2}|f(a_n^2)-f(a_m^2)|+\dfrac{|f(a_m^2)||a_m^2-a_n^2|}{(1+a_n^2)(1+a_m^2)}\le \dfrac{1}{2}|f(a_n^2)-f(a_m^2)|+\dfrac{|f(a_m^2)|}{4}|a_m^2-a_n^2|$$

and $\{a_n^2\}, \{f(a_n^2)\}$ are Cauchy sequences.